# Automatically redirect not logged in users to the login page

Tags: yii2, access-control

Currently I have the problem that not logged in users can access the website if they enter a specific URL.

My site controller looks like this:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    [...]
}
```

That does not work, users can still access the website.

Another caveat: The login page is a different URL https://login.mywebsite.com whereas my website is http://anotherwebsite.com

For `actionIndex` it works:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->render('index');
        }
        else {
            //$this->callback();
            $this->redirect('https://login.mywebsite.com');
        }
    }
```

I want this to be the default if not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `'only' => ['logout'],` from `public function behaviors()` or add `'index'`

docs about only:

> - @var array list of action IDs that this filter should apply to. If this property is not set,
>
>   - then the filter applies to all actions, unless they are listed in [[except]].